# How to schedule a job in Oracle database to repeat 5 times a day in specific hours

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, jobs

I need to schedule a job in the Oracle database to repeat 5 times a day in specific hours, Usually, I will use SQL developer and schedule the job in repetitive mode but in this case it won't work, also I want to avoid creating 5 jobs in different hours so I wonder if there is a way to do this with just one job, thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a SCHEDULER JOB:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
       job_name        => 'THE_NAME'
      ,start_date      => CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
      ,repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=1;BYHOUR=00,04,08,15,18;BYMINUTE=00'
      ,end_date        => NULL
      ,job_class       => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      ,job_type        => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
      ,job_action      => ...
      ,comments        => ...
    );
END;
```